# Hide refiners depending on the selected browser language - Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, search, sharepoint-server, jquery, search-results

in Sharepoint 2013, I have two managed properties xyz_en and xyz_fr for a name column. I would like to show xyz_en and hide xyz_fr if the browser language is en.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Each managed property shown in refiner, renders a `div` with a `refinername` attribute, which actually defines managed property's html mockup. Below is the sample code:

```
//check the language    
var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
if(language == "en-US"){
//hide/show Managed property's div           
     $("div[refinername='xyz_fr']").hide();
     $("div[refinername='xyz_en']").show(); }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How do I insert this to results.aspx? I tried to add Script Editor web part and it did not work...

Comment: Open the developer tool bar and dig into why it didn't work. I can think if jQuery library may not be referenced before the script.

Comment: OK. I saved the html code aside and applied some trouble shooting. It looks like the code you provided reads the windows user account language preference. not browser language.

Comment: Here is what I did:
- Checked if jQuery is loaded [link](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.ca/2009/03/check-if-jqueryjs-is-loaded.html)
- After that tried to print out the div id `document.write($("div[refinerName='refiner_name_EN']").attr("id"));`
the result came out "undefined" some how it is not able to find the div. I also tried to place the code in document.ready and load functions but no luck...

Comment: do you have this code running on a sharepoint 2013 search site? I have a feeling that these refiners are dynamically generated and document.ready function is not able to capture the div created event. So the code you have provided fires before the divs are created.

Comment: Try checking the exact IDs by viewing the Page Source.

Comment: The problem is that the divs are created after document.ready() function.

Comment: `document.ready()` means your entire document has loaded and ready to be parsed, so it is hard to believe if divs are created after that. Try putting some alerts and use browser debugging tools.